# react function undefined when passed to functional component as a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I am passing a function defined in my main app class to a functional component that accepts props. For some reason I'm getting the error that the function is undefined. Can someone help me out? I'ts probably super obvious but I can't think of the reason for the error.

```
//inside APP.js

updateProgress = (val) =>{
    this.setState({progress:val,currentid:val-1}).then(()=>{
      console.log("progress",this.state.progress,"progress",this.state.currentid)
    })
  }

<mycomponent updateProgress={this.updateProgress} mainprops={this.state}/>

// inside functional component script

const cooloptions = props => {
  return (

    props.options.map(o => (
      <div key={o.key}>
        <label htmlFor={o.key}>
            <strong>{o.title}</strong>
            <p>{o.description}</p>
        </label>
        <input id={o.key} name={o.name} onClick={updateProgress(props.mainprops.progress+1)} type="radio" />
      </div>
    ))
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
onClick={updateProgress(props.mainprops.progress+1)}
```

to

```
onClick={()=>props.updateProgress(props.mainprops.progress+1)}
```

Comment: Thanks! this works to define the function :) But now for some reason my progress prop is undefined when the onclick handler runs :(. I can't imagine why because I'm able to console.log() it from inside the component??

Comment: My apologies it was a prop drilling issue I figured it out. Thank you for your help!